# Iterate through the AJAX url in the render from Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

The thing is that i am trying  to fill a datatable like this

```
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+data.name+'\'s row' );
     $.ajax({
 url: data.url,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(json){
 console.log(json)
   tableDos.rows.add([json]).draw();
 }
   });

} );
```

What this does is that when someone selects a row from another datatable that its already filled, it is going to extract the URL of the selected JSON from the row (The JSON comes from SWAPI.CO API) and passed it through to fill another datatable like this.

```
var tableDos = $('#exampleDos').DataTable({
"columns": [{
    "title": "Films",
    "data": "films",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var currentCell = $("#exampleDos").DataTable().cells({"row":meta.row, "column":meta.col}).nodes(0);
  //      $.each(data, function (i, item){  

             $.ajax({
            url: data[0],
            success: function(json){
                console.log(json)
                   $(currentCell).text(json.title);          
            }
        });       
      //  })
        return null;
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Vehicles",
    "data": "vehicles"
  },
   {
    "title": "Starships",
    "data": "starships"
  }
]
 });
```

The tricky part comes here, what this table is receiving is coming from this JSON

```
  {
"name": "Luke Skywalker", 
"height": "172", 
"mass": "77", 
"hair_color": "blond", 
"skin_color": "fair", 
"eye_color": "blue", 
"birth_year": "19BBY", 
"gender": "male", 
"homeworld": "https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", 
"films": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
], 
"species": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
], 
"vehicles": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
], 
"starships": [
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/", 
    "https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
], 
"created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z", 
"edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z", 
"url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
  }
```

So my table as you can see is receiving films, vehicles and starships in the form of an array and URL so i have to do another AJAX call as you can see in the table from for example "films" so i in the AJAX url i have to iterate through the films ARRAY but it automatically iterates without using loops or each and i cant make it work. It seems confusing but check it out for yourselves.

https://jsfiddle.net/um8tmgq2/2/

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but it seems as though you're not using a table as perhaps it should be used. In the example above do you want 2 vehicles under the vehicle header and 2 starships under that header and five films under that column header? If that's the case then that sort of doesn't make sense, surely each film should have its own row... as should each vehicle and starship. Your ajax could be altered as well so that you don't have to hardcode 9 calls but rather use some recursion to get all your data: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/vumm9519/

Comment: Yeah, you are right i didnt explain that. The thing goes like this for example, make the Ajax calls to get the movie titles and store them in a String so i can pass the String to the table and show it like this "The Phantom Menace, The Attack of the Clones, The Revenge of the Sith" and the same for vehicles and starships.